# Error handling with RSYNC

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

What would be the simplest way to check if a remote SSH rsync fails from the host?

I don't care if the file couldn't be found, if a connection couldn't be established, or if RSYNC's dog died and had to attend its funeral. How would I specify:

if RSYNC fails, do something?

EDIT: RSYNC SSH not Daemon.

Comment: Remote meaning `rsync` running in "server mode" or meaning via SSH connection in its own shell interactively? You need to be more precise.

Comment: I'm aware of that, which is why I put this in quotes. Nevertheless when you build a tunnel using SSH (`-e` option), the remote instance behaves similar to a daemon (with `stdin <-> stdout` replacing the listening on a socket). My question was in order to clarify what your scenario looks like. "remote `rsync`" is definitely too broad a question.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Whether or not I'm invoking SSH@server or running rsync directory as a command from a server? I've figured out 1 way to do what I need which I'm posting now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could create a bash script, such as:

```
if ssh <server> rsync; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```